# UPDATE данных в таблице, объединить запросы MYSQL

Tags: mysql

нужно обновить данные по разному alias в таблице, по отдельности эти запросы работают, как их в один объединить?

```
 UPDATE filter_deasc SET act= 
        IF (name='asc',1 ,if(name!='asc',0, act))
        WHERE alias ='sort'
    UNION
    UPDATE filter_deasc SET act= 
        IF (name='name',2 ,if(name!='name',0, act))
        WHERE alias ='sort_field'
```

Comment: запросы объединяются через транзакции

Comment: по идее можно join-ами сделать. Но с головы написать запросы на основе предоставленной информации туговато... (ну может кто и решится на такое)

Comment: noname2019, хотя бы как на этом примере сделать, потому как в интернете примеры с разными таблицами, а мне надо с одной

Comment: @аноним не знаю как вы искали я моментально https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188764/sql-left-join-on-a-single-table по первому запросу нашел (просто сталкивался редко с таким, и делал всего несколько раз)

Comment: noname2019, там выборка, а не обновление данных, причем с разных таблиц, а мне нужно с одной

Comment: @аноним вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436814/mysql-update-table-with-values-from-same-table что бы наверняка... и пишите ник с собачкой в начале, так сразу приходит, не всегда смотрю...

Comment: @noname2019, уже давно решил, просто два метода сделал с двумя запросами